# Process locks up a SQL Server when threading

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, winforms, timer

I have a Windows Form project that uses a `Windows.Forms.Timer` set at 1 minute increments to do different jobs at different times throughout the day.

Some of these processes can take over a minute, then the timer misses the next value. I first thought this was due to threading, so I added a thread for a specific process which queries a remote database. This process locked the database even though the connection via `ODBC` was in a `Using` block.

What kind of async/threading can I use that does not lock a server?

I thought about calling `Abort` on the thread, but how would I know when to call that?

Code:

```
Dim thrd As New Thread(AddressOf SomeServerMethod)
thrd.Start()

Private Sub SomeServerEvent()
  Using myODBC As New ODBCEntity()
    'make query
  End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: When you say locked the database, do you mean locking others from accessing?  What's happening on that side?  Or is it locking up your interface while running?

Comment: It locks the server, not the app. @JimmySmith

Comment: with the query you are running - when you say locked, it's preventing others from accessing the table?  Usually locking is not a default unless the underlying query is instructed to place a hold on the row or table.

Comment: From what I understood from the server team - yes it was locking the entire database (unless I misunderstood them). I do not know about the 'place a hold on the table' part. Thanks @JimmySmith

Comment: It sounds like in this case then the issue is affecting the server's performance - slowing it down, but not locking people out?  You'd have to specify the locking and sounds like that's not the case.  Can you post the query?  Are you doing a `Select * from xTablex`?  You may have to limit your results and set a timeout.  [there's a lot of tricks to improving queries](http://www.developer.com/db/slideshows/10-ways-to-improve-sql-query-performance.html)

Comment: @JimmySmith, It has nothing to do with the query. As my last, it is locking the server. Query executes fine. It'd the thread that is still attached to the process causing the locking. Thanks